# Ember/RSVP Promise value changes when passed to resolve()

Tags: ember.js, rsvp.js

I am trying to wrap a jQuery AJAX request in a Ember RSVP promise, and I have this issue where the value I send to the `resolve` function (which is the `jqXHR` parameter) changes from `object` to `string`.

The code for doing the request + creating the request is as follows:

```
return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  Ember.$.ajax([URL], {
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'text'
  }).then((data, textStatus, jqXHR) => {
    console.log(jqXHR);
    resolve(jqXHR);
  }, (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
    resolve(jqXHR);
  });
});
```

And in my controller, I handle the request like this:

```
promise.then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
  if (response.status === 200) {
    something...
  } else {
    something else...
  }
  receipt.set('busy', false);
});
```

Now, from the basic (and probably flawed) comprehension I have of RSVP.Promise, the `resolve(jqXHR)` line *should* send the `jqXHR` object as parameter to the callback, right?

Problem is, when I print the `response` I get in the console, all I get is `200 success`, which is the body of the HTTP request I do.

However, when I print the `jqXHR` before resolving it, it correctly prints the whole object:

```
Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "200 success", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}
```

So why is this happening? Is Ember doing some wierd black magic and converts the `jqXHR` object to string? Or is the `data` string being sent in lieu of the `jqXHR` object I am expecting?

Thanks!

Comment: You know you can do `Ember.RSVP.resolve($.ajax(...)).then(...)`?

Comment: In `resolve(jqXHR)` try sending data and status too like this `resolve(data,jqXHR.status)`

Comment: @Lux Yes, but the jQuery `ajax` method takes two callbacks, and the `jqXHR` comes first in the `done` callback and third in the `fail` callback, so I am trying to re-arrange the parameters a little bit before resolving my promise.

Comment: @kumkanillam Thanks, it works! But I still can't figure out why the `jqXHR` is converted to string when passed to the promise. Is this normal?

Comment: Don't know about this conversion, may be need to check with source code.

Comment: @kumkanillam Checked what was up in the source code, and I found the answer to my issue. I will post it here as an answer, it that interests you. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

Alright, so apparently `rsvp.js` checks if the object sent to the `resolve` method is 'thenable' (read then-able), i.e. if it contains a `then` method.

If it is 'thenable', it will execute the `then` method of the object, take its first argument (only) and take it as the fulfilled value. This little magic allows chaining resolves but doesn't work very well with callbacks that take multiple arguments.

So in my case, I was sending jqXHR to be resolved, which does contain a `then` method (according to the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR)). RSVP then tried to fulfill the jqXHR object as a promise, and returned the first argument of the `resolve` callback.

Now, the signature for the jqXHR resolve callback is `function(data, textStatus, jqXHR);`, which is why the object sent to MY callback was not `jqXHR` as I expected, but was the first argument of the `jqXHR` resolve callback: `data`.

TL;DR: Check if the object you try to resolve your promise with has a `then` method, because it WILL be executed.